# Why does the humidifier "really" make a stove's flame orange?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, combustion

I answered this question- [Why does the humidifier make a stove's flame orange?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441648/why-does-the-humidifier-make-a-stoves-flame-orange-) and earned 300 rep points for it as an "accepted" answer, but serious doubts have arisen about its correctness.

Doubt is also thereby cast on the legitimacy of the rep I earned.

For this reason I am hereby re-asking the question *and will place those 300 rep points in play as a bounty* for whoever can settle the question with an **experiment**. 
In your answer, please include enough procedural details so others can replicate your experimental results, and discuss those results in light of known physics.

Comment: This is an obvious duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: Kudos.  I had my doubts about that answer, as the flame gets orange if you just turn up the gas too high.

Comment: @pieter, I don't like the idea of  earning rep with wrong answers. If you can think of some other way to remedy this, please inform me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the humidifier make a stove's flame orange?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441648/)

Comment: We do not know if it was wrong. I may be able to do an experiment tomorrow. But with different equipment, it won't be decisive as to what happened in the photo of the original setup.

Comment: This is a great thing to do, but I think you could accomplish the same goal by just putting a bounty on the original question, instead of making a duplicate.

Comment: @knzhou, I didn't know I could put a bounty on  question I had not asked.

Comment: @Pieter - The purpose of the "no duplicates" rule is to avoid having the same question asked and answered over and over again. But in my opinion the special circumstances of this question justify setting aside that rule in this case.

Comment: It's clearly not a duplicate. This question specifically asks for experimental data.

Comment: The only special circumstance seems to be that Nielsen did not know how to ask a bounty. @JohnRennie In the other question, the possibility of taking a spectrum was under discussion. That just takes a bit of time.

Comment: tell me what's best and I will do it.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I don't understand what special circumstances would justify this.  Having multiple incorrect or unsupported answers doesn't make the question invalid or mean we require a new question to answer the same thing.  It just means that the answers are inadequate.

Comment: @Ruslan has now done the experiment, also posted a photo of the spectrum. Clearly the sodium D line.

Comment: @JMac. - Whatever. Just putting in my two cents. Frankly, it's not an issue that I really have strong opinions on or care much about one way or the other.